# Inequality of lim infs and lim sups involving finite measure space

Tags: measure-theory

I am given that $(E,\mathcal{E}, \mu)$ is a finite measure space and I am asked to prove that given a sequence of sets $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ in $\mathcal E$:

$\mu(\lim \inf A_n) \leq \lim \inf \mu(A_n)\leq \lim \sup \mu(A_n) \leq \mu(\lim \sup A_n)$

For the first inequality, I have that:

$$\lim \inf A_n = \bigcup\limits_{N=1}^{\infty} \left(\bigcap\limits_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n\right) \Rightarrow \mu(\lim\inf A_n) = \mu\left(\bigcup\limits_{N=1}^{\infty} \left(\bigcap\limits_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n\right)\right)$$

$$ = \sum_{N=1}^{\infty}\mu\left(\bigcap\limits_{n = N}^{\infty}A_n\right)$$

I now want to bound this from above by $\lim\inf \mu(A_n)$ somehow and all I can think of is that $\mu(A_i) \geq \inf\limits_{i\leq n}\mu(A_n)\; \forall i \in \mathbb N$ since:

Either $\mu(A_i) = \inf\limits_{i\leq n}\mu(A_n)$ or $\inf\limits_{i\leq n}\mu(A_n) = \inf\limits_{i+1\leq n}\mu(A_n)$

But I can't see any nice way that this would let me bound each term in the sum or anything. If I had $\mu(A_i) \leq \inf\limits_{i\leq n}\mu(A_n)$ then by countable subadditivity of $\mu$ I would be done, so do I even have the inequality the right way around?

I am having similar problems with the other inequalities as well so is there something simple that I am missing?

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(\cap_{N=n}^\infty A_N )$ increases to $\liminf_n A_n$. Now using the continuity of probability we have
$$P(\liminf_n A_n) = \lim_n P(\cap_{N=n}^\infty A_N) = \liminf_n P(\cap_{N=n}^\infty A_N) \leq \liminf_n P(A_n).$$